# Adding all videos from a YouTube channel to a website

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

I'm trying to feed videos from a YouTube channel to a website. I've been able to add the videos one by one but I would like to add the whole YouTube channel very interactively on the website. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Data API v3, you can get a list of all playlists associated with your channel.
'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#properties' ->
'contentDetails.relatedPlaylists'

Iterating through these playlists, you can get video ids and feed them.
'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource' ->
'contentDetails.videoId'

---

Or you can put the whole playlist as a player by,

going to playlists -> 
'player.embedHtml'